# Passing char *** at pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, unix

(this is shorted codes)

char** on pthread_create, works well.

```
int main()
{
    char *data[RO] = { /*texts*/ };

    pthread_t thread_t;
    int status;

    if (pthread_create(&thread_t, NULL, pthreadM, (void *)data) < 0)
    {
        perror("thread create error:");
        exit(0);
    }
    pthread_join(thread_t, (void **)&status);
    printf("Thread End %d\n", status);
    return 1;
}

void *pthreadM (void* data)
{
    char **_data = (char **)data;
    print_number(_data[i]);
}
```

but below which id just added *, char*** makes error. Why does this happen?

```
char *data[][]= ~

if (pthread_create(&thread_t, NULL, pthreadM, (void *)data) < 0)
{
    perror("thread create error:");
    exit(0);
}
void *pthreadM (void* data)
{
    char ***_data = (char ***)data;
    print_number(_data[1][i]);
}
```

this is print_number()

```
void print_number(const char *data)
{
    printf("%s", data);
}
```

Comment: I was gonna say something about the shortened code not being a proper [mcve], but then I noticed you try to be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Don't do that.

Comment: Oh, and arrays are not pointers.

Comment: The `~` in `char *data[]= ~
pthread_create(&thread_t, NULL, pthreadM, (void *) data)` looks very suspicious. This is hopefully not part of your real project. Probably not - as the `;` is missing afterwards. Are you aware that [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) returns a success/error code - not the result of the passed thread function?

Comment: `char [x][y]` won't decay to `char***` if passed to a function but to `char(*)[y]`

Comment: I've just learned pthread, and i was testing it. Sorry for bad question, and bad english. I've edited(added) as you said

Comment: This might be an intersting read: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: The issue you are facing isn't related the threading at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` is something like

```
char *data[X][Y] = { { "abc", "def", ... }, ... };
```

`data` is passed as `(void *) data` to `pthread_create`, as you did.

In the thread body, for such a complex object, it is probably easier and safer to make a pointer to the original type, like

```
void *mythread(void *p) {
  char *(*pd)[][Y] = p;
```

and use it like this

```
  (*pd)[0][1] = "hello";
```